# HTML Field; set PHP Array after json_encode - Send to Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I am setting an array with PHP within an html input field and eventually sending that array to a jquery function.

This was not working so I then proceeded to use json_encode and send it that way.  However, since I am setting it within a html field (name), it would not render because of characters.  I then got it working by using htmlspecialchars.

```
//html php
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row)); ?>" />

//jquery
var arr = $('#someAssetDiv input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){
          return $(this).attr('name');
}).get();

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
//which sends back what I need but I am applying htmlspecialchars
```

However, my question is, on the jquery side - how do I go about modifying it back to standard object prior to applying htmlspecialchars?

My end goal is to loop through each object sent and dance with them.

Is there something built in to the Jquery lib that I have not found?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: and where are the codes?

Comment: Give the checkbox an id (eg my_checkbox) and then parse the json array and assign it to a variable: `var arr = JSON.parse($('#my_checkbox').attr('name'))`

Comment: Ah, how I often long to dance with JSON objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have an example of that `$row`, in this case I'l just create a sample data. In this case, you could use `$.parseJSON` of jQuery. [Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dqKrmo)

```
<?php
// PHP
$values = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'test1'),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'test2'),
);

?>

<!-- form with echoed with json encode -->
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="array" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($values)); ?>" />
    <button type="button" id="button">Test</button>
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        var json_value = $('input[name="array"]').val();
        json_value = $.parseJSON(json_value);
        console.log(json_value);
    });
});
</script>
```

But I suggest if you want some data on the server, use `$.ajax` instead, then map the return values.

Comment: thanks for this I am reading through it now.  I can explain more... main area of page lists some data, in addition there is a side tab that lists unused data items.  User can select additional items by checkbox, click save.  This in turn is where I wanted to send those chosen additional items and their data to Jquery and then update the main DOM area.

Comment: @user3417476 its okay to have some context, but still isn't clear to me, what should be the end goal here?

Comment: Ghost I think it worked! Console is now showing correct objects parsed correctly... I think.  End goal is to add items to a list. Once I have a correct array of objects I can then iterate through them and update the list in its entirety.

Comment: @user3417476 if the console can properly see the objects, then the objects are correctly parsed

Comment: @user3417476 since its parsed now, it can be used with `$.map` now, glad this helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a php array into javascript you can try with JSON:

```
<script>
  var json_arr = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>");
  console.log(json_arr);
</script>
```

Then you can get the values:

```
var value = json_arr[0]; //or
var value = json_arr.somekey;
```

**NOTE:** If you put that js in a external file.js, you will get an error beacuse php code not work on external files except .html, so put that  in your html code